# why category name is null when select join with enry table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables ...first is entry

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entry` (
  `entry_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entry_cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `entry_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `entry_body` text NOT NULL,
  `img_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image_link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `entry_state` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `entry_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `entry_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=41 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `entry`
--

INSERT INTO `entry` (`entry_id`, `entry_cat_id`, `entry_name`, `entry_body`, `img_url`, `image_link`, `entry_state`, `comment_count`, `entry_count`, `entry_created`) VALUES
(27, 15, 'title fot entry', 'content', '', '', 0, 0, 0, '2013-04-14 14:47:56');
```

and the escond is entry_category

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entry_category` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `cat_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `entry_category`
--

INSERT INTO `entry_category` (`category_id`, `category_name`, `slug`, `cat_created`) VALUES
(10, 'rrrrrrrr', 'rrrrrrr', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(15, 'gggggg', 'ttttttttt', '2012-12-10 13:47:28');
```

when select with inner join to get the category and entry name i see category_name is null

```
SELECT entry.entry_id, entry_category.category_name, entry.entry_name
FROM entry
INNER JOIN entry_category
ON entry.entry_id=entry_category.category_id;
```

why and what i shall do to see the the category name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

join is having wrong clause

you need to join on category_id but in entry table category_id is in entry_cat_id field so you can join like this

```
    SELECT entry.entry_id, entry_category.category_name, entry.entry_name
    FROM entry
    INNER JOIN entry_category
    ON entry.entry_cat_id=entry_category.category_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are joining on the wrong field.  You are joining on the entry.entry_id field when I think you want to be joining on the entry.entry_cat_id field.

Try changing your query to:

```
SELECT entry.entry_id, entry_category.category_name, entry.entry_name
FROM entry
    INNER JOIN entry_category
        ON entry.entry_cat_id=entry_category.category_id;
```

BTW -- your existing query shouldn't return any results from your sample data.  To see `NULL` records from your entry_category table, you'd need to use an `OUTER JOIN`.